# azure map will not render markers in correct position

Tags: vue.js, azure-maps

I am trying to render a simple Azure Map in a vue.js single-file component.  I can get the map to draw at a specified center and zoom.  And draw a line segment exactly where I want it.

But I cannot draw a marker properly.  It does draw, but it is seriously south-west from the specified coordinate (which is on the an endpoint of a line segment drawn previously).

Here's a single page Vue.js 'App.vue':

```
<template>
    <div id="myMap"></div>
</template>

<script>
import * as atlas from "azure-maps-control";

export default {
  mounted: function() {
      this.map = new atlas.Map("myMap", {
        center: [-113.666783, 53.806008],
        zoom: 7,
        view: "Auto",
        authOptions: {
          authType: "subscriptionKey",
          subscriptionKey: "<redacted>",
        },
      });

      let self = this;

      //Wait until the map resources are ready.
      this.map.events.add("ready", function() {
        //Create a data source and add it to the map.
        var dataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
        self.map.sources.add(dataSource);

        //Create a line and add it to the data source.
        dataSource.add(
          new atlas.data.LineString([
            [-112.926043, 53.803],
            [-113.666783, 53.806],
          ])
        );

        //Create a line layer to render the line to the map.
        self.map.layers.add(
          new atlas.layer.LineLayer(dataSource, null, {
            strokeColor: "blue",
            strokeWidth: 5,
          })
        );

        //Create an HTML marker and add it to the map.
        var marker1 = new atlas.HtmlMarker({
          color: "DodgerBlue",
          position: [-112.926043, 53.803],
          anchor: "bottom",
          htmlContent: '<div class="pulseIconNormal"></div>',
          popup: new atlas.Popup({
            content:
              '<div style="padding:10px">Sensor</div>',
            pixelOffset: [0, -30],
          }),
        });

        self.map.markers.add(marker1);
        //Add a click event to toggle the popup.
        self.map.events.add("click", marker1, () => {
          marker1.togglePopup();
        });
      });
    }
}
</script>

<style>

#myMap {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.pulseIconNormal {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
</style>
```

When I looked at DOM for the marker (in Firefox dev tools), this is the style that I see:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -100%) translate(737px, 235px) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
```

This isn't coming from CSS, but is in inline.  That's the reason, but not the explanation why.  It appears the control itself is generating this.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.  I am using NPM to load azure-maps-control and I had to explicitly add

```
<style src='azure-maps-control/dist/atlas.min.css'></style>
```

to the .vue file.

Answer (score 0):

The map div in your code isn't closed properly. Instead of `<div id="myMap" />` it should be `<div id="myMap"></div>`. HTML standards say self closing div's are invalid. Give that a try and see if it helps.

If it doesn't try inspecting the HTML marker DOM to see if any CSS is being appended to it by your app and try adjusting to see if it addresses the issue.

Looking at your code, the HTML marker should be anchored bottom center to its position.

Comment: edited sample code. no change.  Checking the CSS now in the DOM.

Comment: The position transform is inline and coming from the map control probably.  Edited the OP.

Answer (score 0):

For the same problem with Angular (11), I had to add the azure css file to my angular.json like so:

```
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/azure-maps-control/dist/atlas.min.css"
            ],
```